# Rails : Get multiple column values for single record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I want to get `values` of multiple columns (hopefully as an array) of a single record. I have the `column names` as an array of string.

Something like:

```
Model.first.select([:id,:name,:col1,:col2]).values
#=> [1,mrudul,col1_val,col2_val]  

# with column_names as array
# Model.first.select(columns_names.map(&:to_sym)).values
```

The problem is that I've the column names as an array of string. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `#attributes` method which returns a hash of record attributes and extract needed values from it:

```
columns = [:id,:name,:col1,:col2]
model = Model.find(42)

model.first.attributes.extract!(*columns)
```

Answer (score 1):

this works I think

```
column_names = ['id','name']

Model.where(id: 123).pluck(column_names.join(','))
```

or using select

```
Model.select(column_names.join(',')).where(id: 123)
```

or

```
Model.select(column_names.join(',')).first
```

Answer (score 1):

You could invert the map and use it on your list of columns:

```
model = Model.first
["id", "name", "col1", "col2"].map { |column| model.read_attribute(column) }
```

Comment: This works fine. @freemanoid solution seems more compact though, if you look at the [source](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/attributes), it uses the same `read_attribute` method. Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 0):

Just add method to your model and call it from the instance.

Example:

```
class Address
  def formatted_address
    [address_line, city, pincode, state, country].compact.join(', ').titleize.gsub(', ,',' ')
  end
end
```

In your case, it will be.

```
class Model
  def pick_columns
    [:id,:name,:col1,:col2]
  end
end
```

Call the method:

```
Model.first.pick_columns
#=> [1,mrudul,col1_val,col2_val]
```

You can perform any operation OR just return an array from a method.

Answer (score 0):

based to freemanoid, I use

```
columns = %w[id name col1 col2]
model = Model.find(42)

model.first.attributes.extract!(*columns)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).